# run time exception raised in code

Tags: c++, tbb

i am implementing one algorithm in which i have used thread library of CPP and Intel TBB Library for MultiCore.while i am calling function with the help of thread some times it executes perfectly and sometimes it gives run time exception.i am trying to find cause but couldn't find . Please find the code snippet example which is giving exception.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tbb/pipeline.h>
#include <tbb/atomic.h>
#include <tbb/concurrent_queue.h>
#include <tbb/compat/thread>
#include <tbb/tbbmalloc_proxy.h>    
using namespace std;
using namespace tbb;

#define pi 3.141593
#define FILTER_LEN  265


class MyBuffer 
{
    public:
    double *acc;
    double *buffer;
    int start,end;


    MyBuffer()
    {
        start=0;
        end=0;

       buffer=new double[150264];
       acc=new double[150000];
       fill_n(buffer,150264,0);

    }

    ~MyBuffer()
    {
        delete[] buffer;
        delete[] acc;
    }
    int startnumber()
    {
        return start;
    }
    int endnumber()
    {
        return end;
    }
};




typedef concurrent_queue<MyBuffer>  QueueMyBufferType;
QueueMyBufferType chunk_queue;

atomic<bool> stop_flag;

// input function that will be running by thread to generate sinewave

void input_function()                               
{   
   stop_flag = false;     

   cout<<"thread reached to call input function " <<endl;

   ofstream o("testing sinewave.csv");

   int counter=0;
   while(counter<150000)    
  { 
        cout<<"value of counter is \t" <<counter << endl;
        //MyBuffer *b=new MyBuffer;                                                     
        MyBuffer b; 
        b.start=(FILTER_LEN-1+(counter));
        b.end=(25264+(counter));

        cout<<"value of b.start is and b.end is "<<b.start<<"\t" <<b.end<<endl;

        for(int i =b.startnumber(); i <b.endnumber(); i++)
         {
                b.buffer[i] = sin(700 * (2 * pi) * (i / 5000.0));
                o<<b.buffer[i]<<endl;   
         }

         chunk_queue.push(b);
         cout<<"object pushed in queue and value of j is \t" <<counter <<endl;
         counter+=25000;
     }

    stop_flag = true;
     cout<<"all data is perfectly generated" <<endl;
}


int main()
{
    thread input_thread(input_function);

    while(!stop_flag)
    {
        //cout<<"waiting for thread " << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n All Data is processed \n\n" << endl;        

    return 0;
}
```

This code is part of application and helps in generating sine wave .Please help to find where i am getting wrong.

Comment: which run time exception it is giving ?

Comment: *"... some times it executes perfectly and sometimes it gives run time exception ..."*. A likely symptom of a data race and therefore will fall in the *undefined behavior* land.

Comment: @NetStarter after printing on console all the outputs it gives this exe has stop working ....

Comment: @JasdeepSinghArora using try catch is a best practice...

Answer (score 1):

In :

```
b.end=(25264+(MyBuffer::j));
```

`25264+(MyBuffer::j)` may go out of the boundaries of member array `buffer`

bound check `MyBuffer::j<150000` may be `MyBuffer::j<150000-25264`

```
while(counter<150000-25264)    
  {  ... }
```

Comment: but i am checking all the cases even i have replaced it with local counter still its not working

Comment: @Jasdeep Singh Arora, if you can update your code it would be helpful

Comment: code is updated .After all values on console it gives this exe has stopped working